# WebRTC on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: archlinux, chromium, webrtc

We are trying to run WebRTC in a browser on the Pi, but we won´t get it working. IceWeasel or Chromium won´t show any video stream, just blank windows. We are using Raspbian right now as the operating system.

Has anyone ever see a working video stream in a browser on the Pi? Does it make sense to install Arch Linux and use Firefox? Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to see WebRTC video streams coming from other devices with the following process:

1. Run Raspbian Jessie on a Raspberry Pi 2
2. Install Chromium (https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=121195)
3. Use Chromium to join a WebRTC chat through Jitsi Meet (https://meet.jit.si/)

Unfortunately I've been unable to stream video from my USB camera connected to my Raspberry Pi, but I can see video streams coming from other devices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You should look into this new experimental OpenGL driver, see here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/another-new-raspbian-release/
And maybe try out UV4L for WebRTC streaming from the Pi.